# Add a desktop shortcut to all users in a specific group?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, installshield, shortcut

Currently during the installation of my application I place a special shortcut under a specific account, however this limits the user from having more then 1 special account - instead I have decided to create a specific GROUP and any user in this group should have the special shortcut.

Problem is, I am not able to find anyway to "place a shortcut on all users in a group".

Note the following:

- Must work for Windows 7 and XP
- Can use any programming tools or language (script, C#, install shield, anything goes)
- the groups is something I create (so if I need to do something to the group to make it possible I don't mind)

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no way to do this in an all-users sort of way using Windows Installer or InstallShield.  I once worked on a project that had similar requirements and the only thing we could do was a run-once type postinstall utility that created the shortcut for a user in their profile if they were a member of the group.

What I'd personally suggest, depending on your app,  is to have a generic launcher shortcut for your application for all-users and then show menu options based on group membership.